# Why does echo "a']" | grep -E "\'" not match?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Based on [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41325348/1270789), I have discovered that:

```
echo "a']" | grep -E "\a"
```

Matches OK.

```
echo "a']" | grep -E "\]"
```

Matches OK.

But:

```
echo "a']" | grep -E "\'"
```

Does not match. I cannot find any documentation to describe how exactly `grep -E` handles escaping a single quote. I am using GNU grep 2.16 on Ubuntu 14.04.

NB:

```
echo "a']" | grep -E "'"
```

Matches OK, but I am curious as to how `grep -E` is interpreting `\'`.

**Update:**

I've just tried this on Cygwin 2.6.1 and grep 2.27 and I can reproduce. Using `grep --colour -Eo` perhaps gives a clearer OK/Fail result?

Comment: On a similar (14.04, grep 2.16) system, I can not reproduce, grepping `"\'"` does match. I'm not sure what's going on here, ...

Comment: Your update tells about `grep -Eo`: note that when I add the `-o` to my grep, nothing's written to stdout (now that's unexpected, AFAIU/not being familiar with that option) yet grep returns with 0 (not 1), which indicates that something was matched.

Comment: @SYN: That is the same behavior that you get for `grep -o ""` or ``grep -Eo ""`` — as steeldriver suggested, an empty pattern patches every line, but matches zero characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not just GNU grep, with GNU sed and GNU awk: `echo "a']" | sed "s/\'/foo/"` -> `a']foo` and `echo "a']" | awk "{sub(/\'/,\"foo\")}1"` -> `a']foo`. When you run awk in POSIX mode it does not do that but instead exhibits the expected behavior: `echo "a']" | awk --posix "{sub(/\'/,\"foo\")}1"` -> 
`afoo]`.

The issue is that there is a GNU-ism that `\'` means the same as `$`, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html:

```
Additional GNU Extensions
....
The anchor \` (backtick) matches at the very start of the subject string,
while \' (single quote) matches at the very end.
```

If anyone has a use-case where `\'` is different from `$` I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Yep, they're _GNU_ operators, more specifically [_buffer operators_](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Buffer-Operators.html)